# При получении данных в LocalDateTime из json файла: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, gson

Я пытаюсь спарсить данные с json файла и мне нужно получить birthday в LocalDateTime, но выходит ошибка

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 12 column 20 path $.data[0].birthday
```

Я не могу понять, как исправить эту ошибку.

Сам код

```
public class Datum{
        public int id;
        public Status status;
        public Name name;
        public BigDecimal monthlySalary;
        public LocalDateTime birthday;
        public String username;
        public String password;
        public List<String> emails;
        public String phoneNumber;
        public Location location;
        public String website;
        public String domain;
        public Job job;
        public CreditCard creditCard;
        public String uuid;
        public String objectId;
    }
```

Класс который запускает парсер

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.example.Parser.Root;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class RunParser {
    
    public Root run(){
        Gson g = new Gson();
        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("demo/src/main/resources/data.json")) {
            Root root = g.fromJson(reader, Root.class);
            return root;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Чет не работает опять..." + e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }
    
}
```

Json Файл

```
{
      "id": 6958064,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "name": {
        "first": "Chadrick",
        "middle": "Bailey",
        "last": "Beatty"
      },
      "monthlySalary": "873.00",
      "birthday": "1984-10-17T01:43:46.668Z",
      "username": "Chadrick-Beatty",
      "password": "a3shYp4RtKOczzS",
      "emails": [
        "Dejah62@gmail.com",
        "Lorna_Lowe17@example.com"
      ],
      "phoneNumber": "684.592.9283 x13888",
      "location": {
        "street": "84436 Brooke Avenue",
        "city": "New Earlineworth",
        "state": "Florida",
        "country": "Turkmenistan",
        "zip": "98029-5397",
        "coordinates": {
          "latitude": -39.0855,
          "longitude": -36.2158
        }
      },
      "website": "https://delicious-ant.org/",
      "domain": "somber-dimension.net",
      "job": {
        "title": "Product Research Agent",
        "descriptor": "Product",
        "area": "Research",
        "type": "Executive",
        "company": "Hintz, Rutherford and Kerluke"
      },
      "creditCard": {
        "number": "4477-2259-3629-9212",
        "cvv": "999",
        "issuer": "diners_club"
      },
      "uuid": "4e3596dd-d6f5-4509-ae95-86d7c13b54c5",
      "objectId": "654f75dde4b0b49c824555d0"
    },
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` - объект, при парсинге json ожидается, что значение `birthday` будет объектом и будет начинаться с `BEGIN_OBJECT`, т.е. с `{`, а у вас строка

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример JSON-данных, чтобы было понятно, в каком формате записана дата в поле `birthday`

Comment: Также похоже, что у вас не хватает десериализатора для типа `LocalDateTime` из строки, который следует зарегистрировать при помощи метода `GsonBuilder::registerTypeAdapter`, см. [вопрос "Как реализовать код задачи?" и ответ к нему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210900/)